# Rank result set based on generated random number

Tags: t-sql

I have a T-Sql query that generates a random number for each record. What I would also like to do is to either add Rank or Row_Number column

I have tried both Rank and Row_Number, but I get the following error when I put an int in the order by clause:

> Windowed functions, aggregates and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not
>   support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions

```
SELECT      TOP(4) PERCENT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Getdate(),103) RunDate
        , EM.EmpCode 'Emp Code'
        , D.DepotDepotDescription 'Depot'
        , cast(rand(checksum(newid())) * 10 as decimal(8, 6)) [Random Number]
        , rank() OVER (order by 100) Row
FROM        ttimport.EmployeeMaster EM 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.PayrollFrequency PF ON EM.FrequencyDesc = PF.DescCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Departments DPT ON EM.DepartmentName = DPT.DescCode
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Depot D ON EM.DepotDepotDescription = D.DescCode

ORDER BY 4
```

Comment: `order by 100` does not actually do any ordering at all, as you are ordering by a static value.  What are you trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I think I see what your problem is here.  I am assuming you want to `rank` based on the `[Random Number]` value?  If that is the case, carry on reading!

---

You can't use a constant in an `order by` and expect it to sort in any way, which is why your current script throws an error, as `rank` requires a sort order.

To reference your `Random Number` column you just need to wrap it in another `select` or use a `cte` to the same end:

```
WITH data AS
(

    SELECT      TOP(4) PERCENT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),Getdate(),103) RunDate
            , EM.EmpCode 'Emp Code'
            , D.DepotDepotDescription 'Depot'
            , cast(rand(checksum(newid())) * 10 as decimal(8, 6)) [Random Number]
    FROM        ttimport.EmployeeMaster EM 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.PayrollFrequency PF ON EM.FrequencyDesc = PF.DescCode
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Departments DPT ON EM.DepartmentName = DPT.DescCode
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ttimport.Depot D ON EM.DepotDepotDescription = D.DescCode
)
SELECT *
      , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Random Number]) AS Ranking
FROM data
ORDER BY 4
```

Comment: @DavidCleeton  Why do you want to do this?  Is it for data sampling?  If so there are mych more efficient ways build into to SQL Server, such as [`tablesample`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1308/retrieving-random-data-from-sql-server-with-tablesample/)